Issue with Error Code 48 When Connecting to MongoDB in Azure Functions
I'm currently deploying my project on Azure Functions, with each function running in a separate function app. I’m using a centralized MongoDB database through Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB and accessing it with Mongoose, including defined schema files.
However, I'm encountering a persistent error code 48 every time I invoke a function and attempt to connect to MongoDB. To reiterate, each time I read/write data, the system tries to create the collection by issuing a CREATE command, and fails with a Error Code 48 since the collection exists. Our DB logs have thousands of failed CREATE queries and is messing up our analytics. This is causing major issues with system performance as well.
Here are some additional details:

Environment: Azure Functions
Database: Cosmos DB with MongoDB API
ORM: Mongoose
Error Code: 48 (namespace already exist)

I would appreciate any insights or solutions to resolve this issue. Thank you!
We’ve tried sharing a single model object that contains all schema definitions across multiple functions in our application. To enhance connection efficiency, we also set up a MongoDB connection pool using options in mongoose.connect. We attempted setting overwriteModels to true, as shown below:
`import { model, Document, Schema, Date, models } from "mongoose";


interface IUser extends Document {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  userName: string;
  email: string;
  dateOfBirth?: string;
  selectedCountry: string;
  gender: string;
  receiveEmails: boolean;
}

const userSchema: Schema<IUser> = new Schema<IUser>({
  firstName: { type: String },
  lastName: { type: String },
  userName: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Username is required"],
    minLength: [6, "Username should be at least 6 characters"],
    maxLength: [48, "Username should be at max 48 characters"],
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
  },
  dateOfBirth: {
    type: String,
  },
  selectedCountry: { type: String },
  gender: { type: String },
  receiveEmails: { type: Boolean }
});
userSchema.index({ userName: 1});
userSchema.index({ email: 1});

export const UserModel = models.Users ||  model('Users', userSchema,'users',{ overwriteModels: true });`

However, this approach still doesn’t work as expected. Any insights on improving model sharing or handling model overwrites across multiple functions would be appreciated.

refer to link for Manage a collection in Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB using JavaScript

Error Code 48 in MongoDB typically indicates that you are attempting to create a collection that already exists.
This can happen when the application tries to register a Mongoose model multiple times.
I have checked the documentation for Mongoose using this link and used dropCollection, similar to your approach.
However, from the documentation, there is an official method to drop a collection.
It is advisable to use the mongodb package to drop the collection. Refer to this GitHub repository for the complete code in JavaScript.

I referred to this document to create, drop, and retrieve a collection in Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB.

const  indexes = await  collection.indexes();
console.log(`Indexes on collection:\n${JSON.stringify(indexes, null, 2)}`);
const  dropCollectionResult = await  db.dropCollection(collectionName);
console.log(`Collection dropped: ${dropCollectionResult}`);
} catch (error) {
console.error("Error connecting to Azure Cosmos DB:", (error  as  Error).message);


Output:

